# Data model in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm learning Swift and I have a question about data model or the Model folder in Xcode. During a project 'Quiz app' we opened a new swift file in Model folder and started to write some code in it.

What is Data model and why instead of writing all the code just in the ViewController file we need to write a separate one in the model folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could, technically, have all the code for your app in a single file. But it would quickly become really hard to find somethig and keep it readable. Also, when working in bigger teams, having a lot of code in few files results in merge conflicts, which could quickly get out of hand.

It is simply a good practice to keep all your classess in separate files, grouped in folders.

As for what a „data model” is - it’s just a representation of your domain problem in code. These classess will most likely represent data you retrieve from web, or create in app to perform some further operations on them or to use them as input for views to present them to the user.

Comment: Thank you very much Losiowaty !!!, now I got a better idea  !